# Windows to Linux (rsync and ssh)

Tags: linux, ssh, windows, rsync

I'm trying to backup the folders in Windows Pictures to a remote Linux directory.

This is what I have:

`rsync -av ssh /cygdrive/c/users/Owner/Pictures/ blah@192.168.1.10:/var/files/ImageSync/`

I got this format from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182286/transferring-from-windows-to-linux-with-rsync

But I am getting this error:

`rsync: link_stat "/home/Owner/ssh" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/cygdrive/c/users/Owner/Pictures" failed: No such file or directory (2)
sent 20 bytes  received 12 bytes  64.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1165) [sender=3.1.1]`

I have an `ssh` key pair already linked up, so there is no need for a password. Unless I did something wrong and that's why I am having issues.

I have also tried:

`rsync -av -e ssh /cygdrive/c/users/Owner/Pictures/ blah@192.168.1.10:/var/files/ImageSync/`

and get the same error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I you have to pass the source folder before you state the `-av -e` switch:

```
$ rsync /cygdrive/c/users/Owner/Pictures/ -av -e ssh blah@192.168.1.10:/var/files/ImageSync/
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried this and still receiving `rsync: change_dir "/cygdrive/c/AlinaWendt/Pictures" failed: No such file or directory (2)` Could it be an issue with the cygdrive? I have Cygwin64 installed

Comment: Sounds like the source folder "/cygdrive/c/AlinaWendt/Pictures" doesn't exist. Can you make sure you don't have a type in there? `$ ls -la /cygdrive/c/AlinaWendt/Pictures`

Comment: getting `ls: cannot access /cygdrive/c/AlinaWendt/Pictures: No such file or directory` What can I do about this

Comment: Well, the reason of this error message is simple. The directory doesn't exist. Where do you get that format of the source folder from? Also, what directory do you actually want to process? The system where you invoke the rsync command, is a Windows or Linux system?

Comment: Got it to finally work by manually opening the ports through `cd`, so had to `cd /cygdrive` then `ls` ... so on and so forth. Was opening "C:/Users/AlinaWendt/Pictures" on Windows to blah@192.168.1.10 Linux. Then your method worked. Thanks!

Comment: What you wrote in your answer wouldn't make any difference.